# Howto handle C++ static lib dependencies of third party static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

can someone explain why im getting LINK-Errors on the following setup:

i have a static C++ **MyOwnLib.lib** which uses a few static third party **LibA.lib, LibB.lib, LibC.lib**. Only **MyOwnLib.lib** is using some of the implementations of this third party libs, therefore i #included all the third party libs in the MyOwnLib.**cpp** file instead of the MyOwnLib.**h** file.

**Now:**
when i build MyOwnLib.lib its working without errors.

But when i use/link **MyOwnLib.lib** to my Tool.exe project im getting LINK errors to methods/types which belong to the third party libs although im only using the methods/types in the MyOwnLib.**cpp** file.

I dont even use any of the third party methods in my Tool.exe project.

What i fount out: there are a few more .lib files that belong to the third party library I use, that I don't really need, but as soon as I link them to **MyOwnLib.lib** , I don't get LINK errors in my Tool.exe project anymore. However, this "not needed libs" makes **MyOwnLob.lib** very large, which I actually want to avoid.

I was searching for similar problems, but did not find an explanation for that.

**UPDATE:**
I just found out, that a class which is forward declared using pIndom can use types/methods of a third party library and will build/compile correctly even i did **not** link **any** library.

Why does this work ? If i use a type/method in a normal class, im getting LINK errors as expected. ?

Thank you

Comment: maybe not so helpful hint: that probably means  MyOwnLib.lib doesn't contain all it's dependencies.

Comment: If you get linking errors, then the parts of those libraries are used in some way in your `Tool.exe`, e.g. through some dependencies in the included headers.

Comment: I really thought that too but there is nothing included in my Tool.exe project what is related to any of this third party library files .

Answer (score 0):

At link time, a *normal* linker tries to resolve any symbol, whether they will be actually used or not. And if some are missing, it lists them and abort the build.

If you are really sure that they will never be used, a possible trick is to provide a stub defining all those missing symbols as pointers to void or void function and add it to your build. That should be enough for the linker.

If you do not want your application to crash without any message, you could try to be a little more clever, and define all functions or methods with their correct signature to shout an error message and fail fast. The application will indeed be broken but at least you would know where the problem is.

Comment: thank you, but why does building and compiling of MyOwnLib.lib work, and after linking MyOwnLib.lib to my Tool.exe project its giving me LINK errors on types/methods of the used third-party lib ?

Comment: **UPDATE:**
I just found out, that a class which is forward declared using pIndom can use types/methods of a third party library and will build/compile correctly even i did **not** link **any** library. 

Why does this work ? If i use a type/method of that library in a normal class (not forward declared), im getting LINK errors as expected. ?